# C++ Storing to file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

So I need some help to understand why.
The problem is that on the console registries with path are displayed normally, but when I want to store them in the file, the names and the paths becomes some sort of code.

- This is how the message looks on console: 
  https://prnt.sc/mzd1f7 
  This
  is how the message looks on txt file: 
  https://prnt.sc/mzd1wh 
  This is
  the code that I'm working on: 
  https://prnt.sc/mzd1s4

Hope you guys will help me. Thanks!

P.S. The main task is to make the console message to be the same and in the txt file.

Comment: Copy paste the data into your question. Do not use screenshots for this. (At some point they are no longer hosted)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using `wcout` to print out to console. This means that the string is `wide char` which is different from `char` (wchar takes 2 bytes and char takes only 1 byte).

However, `outfile` is obviously not a unicode file stream.

To fix this, try to make `outfile` be a `wfstream` or `wofstream`.